# Getting overlays depends on interactive call (emacs)

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I am experimenting with overlays and I try to find out if the overlays at point contain faces named after `show-paren-match`.

As an example, I got the following code in the `*scratch*` buffer with `|` being the current cursor position:

```
(defun foo1 ()
  (message (format "%S" (overlays-at (point)))))

(defun foo2 ()
  (interactive)
  (foo1))

|(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'foo2)
```

When I type `C-c t`, I get the right number of overlays knowing that I am using smartparens-20150106.757 in emacs-24.4 to highlight matching braces:

```
(#<overlay from 192 to 228 in *scratch*> #<overlay from 192 to 193 in *scratch*>)
```

However, evaluating at that point (`M-:`) using the following expression `(call-interactively 'foo2)` or `(foo2)` returns `nil`. In other examples not shown here, it returns a reduced number of overlays. Using `C-u C-x =` displays all the wanted overlays.
When calling the commmand through `M-x` with prefix argument, it does not show the wanted overlays neither.

Why can't I get the correct amount of overlays at point when calling interactively through `M-x` or in the minibuffer with `M-:` ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Perhaps because when you use `M-:` or `M-x`, your current buffer changes temporarily to the minibuffer (though I'd expect a lot more commands to be affected if that was really the cause).

Comment: I only gave here a simple example. I already tried to set the buffer or even switch to it using `set-buffer` and then go to the desired position with e.g. `(goto-char pos)`.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you look in your `*Messages*` to see if the message is appearing there?  The evaluation echo area display in the minibuffer generally prints non-`nil` if the last line in the code is a direct output -- e.g., throwing a result so to speak.  For example:  `(defun foo-bar () (interactive) "hello-world")`

Comment: Just checked out the `*Messages*` buffer where the output is `nil` too .

Comment: @JSON is right, I think - don't fiddle with `M-:` for such diagnostic work. But your question "*Why can't I...?*" seems to be answered by "You can!", using *your own example* of `foo2`. So the question is unclear, as it stands now.

Comment: I modified the question. I can get the wanted result by using the keybinding `C-c t` but not by invoking the function `foo2` through `M-x` nor `M-:`.